# How to open new SQLite database in runtime with Spring-JDBC?

Tags: sqlite, spring-jdbc

For my desktop application I need to change SQLite database connection in runtime (actually it is just "Open file" action).

Datasource is configured using Spring-JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

1) Extend `SingleConnectionDataSource` to be able to change JDBC URL:

```
public class ChangeableSingleConnectionDataSource extends SingleConnectionDataSource {
    public void updateUrl(String filePath) {
        setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + filePath);
        resetConnection();
    }
}
```

2) Define `dataSource` in `context.xml`

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="package.ChangeableSingleConnectionDataSource" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:"/>
    <property name="suppressClose" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

3) When you need to open a new database file just call

```
dataSource.updateUrl(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
```